# Transport Layer Security Elasticsearch configuration

Tags: security, elasticsearch, kibana, transport-security

**Note :** My version of Elasticsearch is  **7.15.0**

---

I'm new to **Elasticsearch** , I'm trying to use **Kibana alerts** , to do that I must create a **Rule and a Connector** but when I've selected that field I've been got informed to  **enable Transport Layer Security and API keys**  to do so I followed the [Elastic Transport Layer Security  guide instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/security-basic-setup.html#encrypt-internode-communication) where the instructor describe these steps  :

> Encrypt inter-node communications with Transport Layer Security  :
>
> **1.** Open the **$ES_PATH_CONF/elasticsearch.yml** file and make the following **changes**:
> **a.** Add the **cluster-name** setting and enter a name for your cluster:

```
cluster.name: my-cluster
```

> **b.** Add the **node.name** setting and enter a name for the node. The node name defaults to the host-name of the machine when Elasticsearch starts.

```
node.name: node-1
```

> **c.** Add the following settings to enable inter-node communication and provide access to the node’s certificate.
> Because you are using the same **elastic-certificates.p12** file on every node in your cluster, set the verification mode to **certificate**:

```
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.client_authentication: required
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
```

Since the elastic-certificates is not generated automatically during the installation of the Software it must be generated by the **elasticsearch-certutil** inside the **/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin directory** :

**a.** First :

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
```

**b.** run the elastic-certutil to generate the **elastic-stack-ca.zip** certificate file :

```
 bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca
```

**c.** unzip the file to exract the all information and move them to the /etc/elasticsearch directory .

```
unzip elastic-stack-ca.zip
```

Now the problem occurs when starting the elasticsearch service :

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

`Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

I tried to see where the error is located by running  **these two** control commands but I did not understand .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked permissions and owners on the files? Permissions should be at `640` for the files. The owner/group should be `root:elasticsearch`.